# How to I get text from <p> tag using regex applied within BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written some script in python using `regex` to fetch text from certain `p` tags but he script is giving me empty list.

This is the magnetic portion of `html elements`:

```
   <div class="result__links">
        <p class="result__outcome u-hide-phablet">Kolkata Knight Riders won by 7 wickets</p>
        <p class="result__info u-hide-phablet">
            Match 15, 20:00 IST (14:30 GMT), Sawai Mansingh Stadium, Jaipur
        </p>
        <a class="result__button result__button--mc btn" href="/match/2018/15?tab=scorecard">Match Centre</a>
    </div>
```

How do I fetch the text of `p` tag wrapped within the below class?

```
classs='result__info u-hide-phablet'
```

The purpose is to fetch the text of above mentioned tag using `regex`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
winner = soup.find_all('p',class_="result__outcome u-hide-phablet") 
win_list = re.findall(r'>(.*?)</p>', str(winner))
```

The above portion produces empty list. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Post script: I'm looking for any solution related to `regex`.

Comment: You do not have a class `result__info u-show-phablet` in the mentioned html

Comment: I corrected ````result__info u-show-phablet```` to ````result__info u-hide-phablet"````

Comment: Its is working fine with the new data

Comment: But ````re.findall(r'>(.*?)</p>', str(winner))```` does not work on ````soup.find_all('p',class_="result__info u-hide-phablet"````

I would like to know if there is any better way to get the text based on class of any html element and there are lot of records for each class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the tags you are interested in you can do:

```
for p in soup.findAll("p", {"class" : "result__outcome u-hide-phablet"}):
    tags_text = p.text
```

In the same way for span you need to do:

```
for span in soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "result__score result__score--winner"}):
        tags_text = span.text
```

That is to get the text in each tag, as you have asked in your question.

Comment: thanks @Themis... for loop was something I did not try when trying to fetch the text